# css: How to add blank space under a sprint element

Tags: css

I am trying to create a menu out of some hand-written elements in a sprint. Each element has not only its title, but also an underline.

The issue arises when I want to crop the bottom part of an element (the underline) and show it only on hover. I cannot simply give my element a height and increase the height on hover because the elements underneath would flicker and go down, which IMO looks pretty ugly. This is what I have so far:

```
<article style="overflow-y: scroll;" class="menu-container">
      <a class="menu-item menu-about" href='about.html'>About</a>
      <a class="menu-item menu-projects" href='projects.html'>Projects</a>
      <a class="menu-item menu-now" href='now.html'>Now</a>
      <a class="menu-item menu-contact" href='mailto:burnandceline@gmail.com'>Contact</a>
    </article>

.menu-item {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Fb7r7oN.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 43px;
}
.menu-about {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  width: 133px;
  height: 67px;
}
.menu-projects {
  background-position: 0 -147px;
  width: 169px;
}
.menu-now {
  background-position: 0 -216px;
  width: 93px;
}
.menu-contact {
  background-position: 0 -275px;
  width: 164px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zgctwvm/

Comment: You can do it with height, you just make up the height increase/decrease value with a margin-bottom to compensate. This way the elements stays the same. If not this suits you, you can add the background-image to a pseudo element and change its height accordingly.

Comment: If you need help with that, please add the hover effect using height in the way you want to your fiddle and I can help upgrade that to how I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay if the menu items will have more space between them?

The problem is that even if you will play with the background position/size on hover, the text will have to change its location.

I did this:
https://jsfiddle.net/3zgctwvm/8/

```
.menu-item {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Fb7r7oN.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 47px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.menu-item:hover{
  height: 67px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

This way all items have height 47px and margin-bottom 20px, on hover the height changes to 67px and the margin-bottm to 0. 
No menu jumping happeing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pseudo version as well, as I suggested in my comments.

I personally prefer this way as it keeps your original div without the margin and one can easier add animations etc., like I did in below sample.

```css
.menu-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu-item {
  display: block;
  height: 67px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item:after{
  content: "";
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Fb7r7oN.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  transition: bottom 0.3s; 
}
.menu-item:hover:after{
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.3s; 
}

.menu-about:after {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  width: 133px;
}

.menu-projects:after {
  background-position: 0 -147px;
  width: 169px;
}

.menu-now:after {
  background-position: 0 -212px;
  width: 93px;
}

.menu-contact:after {
  background-position: 0 -275px;
  width: 164px;
}
```

```html
<article class="menu-container">
  <a class="menu-item menu-about" href='about.html'></a>
  <a class="menu-item menu-projects" href='projects.html'></a>
  <a class="menu-item menu-now" href='now.html'></a>
  <a class="menu-item menu-contact" href='mailto:somemail@gmail.com'></a>
</article>
```